# Unique object instances in an array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, instances, uniq

I have a custom defined class `Instruction`. Instances are initialized and collected in an array. There are some duplicate (all instance variables identical) instances and I want to filter them out.

```
class Instruction
    attr_accessor :date, :group, :time
    def initialize(date, group, time)
        @date, @group, @time = date, group, time
    end
end

instructions = Array.new

instructions.push ( Instruction.new('2000-01-01', 'Big', '10am') )
instructions.push ( Instruction.new('2000-01-01', 'Small', '9am') )
instructions.push ( Instruction.new('1999-09-09', 'Small', '4pm') )
instructions.push ( Instruction.new('2000-01-01', 'Small', '9am') )

instructions.uniq.each {|e| puts "date: #{e.date} \tgroup: #{e.group} \ttime: #{e.time}"}
```

I would expect one of the `'2000-01-01', 'Small', '9am'` entries removed by `.uniq`, however I still see the repeated entry in the output.

I have tried adding `==` and `eql?` methods to the class definition as follows:

```
def ==(other)
    other.class == self.class && other.date == self.date && other.group == self.group && other.time == self.time
end
alias :eql? :==
```

But that didn't work either... Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `uniq` did not work because, even when the two of the instances of `Instruction` may share the values of `@date`, `@group`, `@time`, their identity are different. You have to compare the values of these instance variables, not the instance of `Instruction` itself.

```
instructions.uniq{|e| [e.date, e.group, e.time]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to override `hash`. `eql?` only gets called for objects with the same `hash` value.

Comment: why single eql? or hash is not enough? I do not understand

Comment: `eql?` only gets called for objects with the same `hash` value, but then it is required. So, only overriding one of them simply does not properly implement the protocol.

Comment: I just wanted to know why simply hash is nit enough to compare? Or eql?, which alone is 100% guarantor of equality? Why do we need them both?